# Extracting and storing all 6x6 postitions from multiple resampled 6x6 matrices in an array in R

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, matrix

I have an array (y) of 500, 6X6 matrices, like this:

```
, , 1
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 0.0000 0.3627 0.4132 0.4231 0.3795 0.5444
[2,] 0.3627 0.0000 0.2084 0.3523 0.2310 0.5377
[3,] 0.4132 0.2084 0.0000 0.1984 0.2920 0.4774
[4,] 0.4231 0.3523 0.1984 0.0000 0.2787 0.4363
[5,] 0.3795 0.2310 0.2920 0.2787 0.0000 0.5129
[6,] 0.5444 0.5377 0.4774 0.4363 0.5129 0.0000

[...]

, , 500
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 0.0000 0.3755 0.3568 0.3835 0.3582 0.5065
[2,] 0.3755 0.0000 0.0840 0.2253 0.2237 0.4066
[3,] 0.3568 0.0840 0.0000 0.1673 0.2434 0.4073
[4,] 0.3835 0.2253 0.1673 0.0000 0.2338 0.3403
[5,] 0.3582 0.2237 0.2434 0.2338 0.0000 0.4263
[6,] 0.5065 0.4066 0.4073 0.3403 0.4263 0.0000
```

I want to extract each matrix position (36) through all the 500 matrices in the array and store the 500 values of each position in a separate vector (36 vectors of 500 values).

Up till now, with the aid obtained here, I can extract the 500 values of a specific position (1,1 in this case) and store them in a vector called, say, "unouno", with this code:

```
unouno<-NULL
for (i in 1:dim(y)[[3]]){
unouno[i]<-y[1,1,i]
}
```

I could write 36 times this code and extract all values, but how could I automate this? Should I use nested loops (I ve tried them unsuccesfully) or is there any other better way?
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this similar to an earlier question posted today?

Comment: `apply(y, 3, "[", 36)` will extract every 36th position

Comment: May be `m1 <- as.matrix(expand.grid(lapply(as.list(dim(y)[1:2]), seq.int)));lapply(split(m1, row(m1)), function(i) y[i[1],i[2],])`

Comment: It was a similar question, so I reedited title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to extract each matrix position, we can transpose the `array` using `aperm`, convert to `matrix` with `nrow` as the third dimension of 'y'.  Each column represents the extracted elements for the position. (Using a reproducible example of dimensions 6,6,2)

```
matrix(aperm(y, c(3,1,2)), nrow=dim(y)[3])
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7] [,8]   [,9]  [,10]  [,11]
#[1,]    0 0.3627 0.4132 0.4231 0.3795 0.5444 0.3627    0 0.2084 0.3523 0.2310
#[2,]    0 0.3755 0.3568 0.3835 0.3582 0.5065 0.3755    0 0.0840 0.2253 0.2237
#      [,12]  [,13]  [,14] [,15]  [,16]  [,17]  [,18]  [,19]  [,20]  [,21] [,22]
#[1,] 0.5377 0.4132 0.2084     0 0.1984 0.2920 0.4774 0.4231 0.3523 0.1984     0
#[2,] 0.4066 0.3568 0.0840     0 0.1673 0.2434 0.4073 0.3835 0.2253 0.1673     0
#     [,23]  [,24]  [,25]  [,26]  [,27]  [,28] [,29]  [,30]  [,31]  [,32]
#[1,] 0.2787 0.4363 0.3795 0.2310 0.2920 0.2787     0 0.5129 0.5444 0.5377
#[2,] 0.2338 0.3403 0.3582 0.2237 0.2434 0.2338     0 0.4263 0.5065 0.4066
#      [,33]  [,34]  [,35] [,36]
#[1,] 0.4774 0.4363 0.5129     0
#[2,] 0.4073 0.3403 0.4263     0
```

#### data

```
y <- structure(c(0, 0.3627, 0.4132, 0.4231, 0.3795, 0.5444, 0.3627, 
0, 0.2084, 0.3523, 0.231, 0.5377, 0.4132, 0.2084, 0, 0.1984, 
0.292, 0.4774, 0.4231, 0.3523, 0.1984, 0, 0.2787, 0.4363, 0.3795, 
0.231, 0.292, 0.2787, 0, 0.5129, 0.5444, 0.5377, 0.4774, 0.4363, 
0.5129, 0, 0, 0.3755, 0.3568, 0.3835, 0.3582, 0.5065, 0.3755, 
0, 0.084, 0.2253, 0.2237, 0.4066, 0.3568, 0.084, 0, 0.1673, 0.2434, 
0.4073, 0.3835, 0.2253, 0.1673, 0, 0.2338, 0.3403, 0.3582, 0.2237, 
0.2434, 0.2338, 0, 0.4263, 0.5065, 0.4066, 0.4073, 0.3403, 0.4263, 
0), .Dim = c(6L, 6L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL, NULL))
```