# vector< vector<int> > with 6x6 dimension implementation

Tags: arrays, c++11, vector

[Extracting and storing all 6x6 postitions from multiple resampled 6x6 matrices in an array in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045944/extracting-and-storing-all-6x6-postitions-from-multiple-resampled-6x6-matrices-i)

i got my answer from here .
[How to create a 2D vector where in like 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823562/multi-dimensional-vector)

Comment: Have you tried this at all?

Comment: Yes you [can](https://ideone.com/Pb9KoE), but it could be better to declare a 1D vector: `vector<int> arr(36);` and to access its elements calculating the right index: `arr[i*6 + j]` instead of `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: '@RadouaneROUFID' Thanks.. Though i didn't understand 'Multidimensional Vector' .so please will you provide a better way to clear my all doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives.  vector of vectors or a single vector (See @Bob__'s comment).

The advantage of the vector of vectors is C++ goodness (iterator bounds checking etc).  The downside is a higher cost of construction/copy. `rows+1` vectors must be constructed (or copied).

The benefit of the single vector of rows*cols size is that you only require a single vector construction (or copy when needed). (Another performance benefit is cache locality of the data.)

Here's how you can preserve the [row][col] syntax.

```
const int rows = 6;
const int cols = 6;
vector<int> x(rows*cols);

//enable using [row][col] syntax
auto a_int = reinterpret_cast<int (*)[rows]>(x.data());
// cout <<  a_int[row][col] << '\n';
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823562/multi-dimensional-vector)_answer of this question is on this link...